# Loading bootstrap-bundle with SystemJS

Tags: bootstrap-4, aurelia, systemjs

I am having an issue where I am unable to load the javascript file that I would like instead of the default.   The application is uing jspm and in my system.js file I have following (trimmed down to what I think is relevant).

```
System.config({
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: false,
  paths: {
    "*": "dist/*",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
  },
  meta: {
    "bootstrap": {
      "deps": [
        "jquery"
      ]
    }
  },
  map: {
    //lots of things omitted
    "bootstrap": "npm:bootstrap@4.0.0",
    "npm:bootstrap@4.0.0": {
       "jquery": "npm:jquery@3.2.1",
       "tether": "github:HubSpot/tether@1.4.3"
     },
  }
}
```

This seems to load cause a `GET` to `http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0.js` which returns

```
module.exports = require("npm:bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap");
```

and then a subsequent request is sent to `http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.js` which returns the full file.

I would like to load `bootstrap-bundle.js` instead as it contains some popper functionality that I need.   What changes do I need to make for this to happen? I've looked at the docs, but beyond "getting started" I really don't grasp whats going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the default distributed .js file of the package with the following setting

```
System.config({
    map: {
        "bootstrap": "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"
    }
});
```